# QGIS updating problems

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall

I had on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the software QGIS 2.0 Dufour. I use the Synaptic Package Manager for uninstalling. I tried to install the newest QGIS version 2.8 Wien but I didn't manage. I searched on the internet for any possible solutions but nothing worked. Please advice.

Comment: @xunilk What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

For installing this software in your system you have to modify the **/etc/apt/sources.list** file to add these lines:

```
#QGIS for 14.04
deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
```

Afterward, in bash console:

1) To add the public key of QGIS:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3
sudo gpg --export --armor DD45F6C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

2) To install last version of QGIS (2.8.x)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```