# dist-upgrade in ubuntu 14.04 uninstalled qgis and results in unmet dependencies

Tags: upgrade, qgis

I did an dist-upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 and it uninstalled QGIS and related packages. I tried to re-install it and I receive the following error about unmet dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  qgis : Depends:
libgdal.so.1-1.11.1 but it is not installable
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-grass but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: qgis-plugin-globe but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS version in the repos of Ubuntu is older that **qgis.org** version. For this reason it is preferable to install with repos of **qgis.org**. Please, see my answer in:

[QGIS updating problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618274/qgis-updating-problems/618307#618307)

Comment: I use the unstablegis wich has the latest qgis version (ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable). I had install it but after the dist-upgrade ... nothing. You use the debian repo. Do you thing is more stable than ubuntu repo?

Comment: This `deb http://qgis.org/debian trusty main` is an Ubuntu repo because has the Ubuntu name version (**trusty**); in my case is **utopic** because I have the 14.10 version.  I think that is preferable to use the stable version. I don't have any problem with my QGIS.

Comment: I try a lot of things but the broken pacage still there.... your solution worked. Thanks a lot.